# Count all 4-letter Substring within the given String that matches ignore case a particular String

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I need to create a program in Java that finds all the occurrences of a 4-letter string, in this case `"lane"`, within the given String.

Comparison should be case-insensitive, and the second letter of the matching substring should not be taken into account while evaluating whether a substring matches or not.

My current code can handle some cases, but in others it returns an incorrect number of occurrences or produces an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I tried the following cases:

1. `"Lanee"` - returns `1`, as expected (`"Lane"` matches `"lane"`).
2. `"LineLone"` - returns `2`, as expected (both `"Line"` and "Lone"`match`"lane"`).
3. `"LLoenLL"` - produces an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
4. `"enaLLLmnee"` - returns `0`, but should be `1`
5. `"LLONElllneL"` - produces an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

*My code:*

```
public class Stringer {

    public Stringer() {}
    
    public int getOccurrences(String s) {

        String lower = s.toLowerCase();
        int occurrences = 0;
        int x = 0;

        while (x < lower.length()) {
            int traverser = lower.indexOf("l", x);
            if (traverser != -1 && lower.length() > 3) {
                String sub = lower.substring(x += 2, x += 2);

                if (sub.equals("ne")) {
                    occurrences++;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return occurrences;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: *enaLLLmnee (returns 0 when it should be 1)*  Why?  Also, are you looking for the string backwards too?  And what do you mean by ignoring second letter?  Please update your question to explain and provide additional detail on what `"works"` means.

Comment: @WJS OP meant that any substring having three matching characters, *except the second one*, like `"LXne"`, can be considered a valid match to the target string `"line"`. Therefore, `"enaLLLmnee"` contains `1` matching substring: `"Lmne"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to iterate over the given string, checking if the current character is equal to `'l'` (*the first character of* `"lane"`).

And if the that's the case, you need to check the if character at the current index `+2` and `+3` match `'n'` and `'e'` respectively. If all these characters match, the number of occurrences should be incremented and the index advanced by `3` to avoid double-checking the same positions.

***Note** that termination condition in the loop is* `i < lower.length() - 3` *because the length of the target string* `"lane"` is `4` *and while checking the first character of a substring at index* `i` *we need to be able to the last substring character at index* `i + 3`.

```
public static int getOccurrences(String s) {
    String lower = s.toLowerCase();
    int occurrences = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lower.length() - 3; i++) {
        if (lower.charAt(i) == 'l' &&
            lower.charAt(i + 2) == 'n' &&
            lower.charAt(i + 3) == 'e') {

            occurrences++; // incrementing the number of occurrences
            i += 3;        // advancing the index
        }
    }
    return occurrences;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("Lanee"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("LineLone"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("LLoenLL"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("enaLLLmnee"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("LLONElllneL"));
}
```

*Output:*

```
1
2
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of regular expressions to solve this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("Lanee"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("LineLone"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("LLoenLL"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("enaLLLmnee"));
    System.out.println(getOccurrences("LLONElllneL"));
}
```

prints

```
1
2
0
1
2
```

Regular expressions can be used to match patterns in strings

- `(?i)` - uses the `i` flag which says ignore case when matching
- `l.ne` - is the string to match. The `.` stands for any character
- the Matcher takes the source string and iterates across the string trying to find matches.  If it returns true, count is updated.

```
public static int getOccurrences(String s) {
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)l.ne").matcher(s);
   int count = 0;
   while (m.find()) {
       count++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

You could also use the following method signature to take *any* target string. Then you just need to build the expression using the target.

```
public static int getOccurrences(String s, String target) {
    String expression = "(?i)"+target.substring(0,1)+"."+target.substring(2);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(s);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Calling it like this, the output would be the same.

```
System.out.println(getOccurrences("Lanee", "lane"));
System.out.println(getOccurrences("LineLone", "LANE"));
System.out.println(getOccurrences("LLoenLL", "LaNe"));
System.out.println(getOccurrences("enaLLLmnee","lanE"));
System.out.println(getOccurrences("LLONElllneL", "Lane"));
```

Comment: I prefer this approach. Though I have a suggestion in order to make a one-liner of it: `return Pattern.compile("(?i)l.ne").matcher(s).results().count();`